# email delivery problem in android app using jar libraries

Tags: android, email

I am developing an application where the email is sent using jar libraries. I am using a custom email account to send email from android app. The following is code of sender activity

```
private String mailhost = "us2.smtp.mailhostbox.com";
public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}
```

The following code is for setting sender and recipient

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(MessageActivity.this,"Sending...", "Please Wait...",true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("apps@softglobe.net", "XXXXXX");
                            //sender.addAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/image.jpg");
                            sender.sendMail("New Message from Arsod Classes App", "New Message from Arsod Classes App\nName: " + nm + "\nEmail: " + em + "\nMessage: " + msg,
                                    "apps@softglobe.net", "softglobe.technologies@gmail.com");

                            MessageActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mail Sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

When I try to send email using the above code, the `Toast` appears saying 'email is sent' but, I it is not receiving at recipient's side.
Similarly, when I try to send email with same credentials using `php` website and `phpmailer` library, then the email is sent successfully. What might be the problem? Please help. I spent lots of hours but did't find any solution. I am using jar libraries provided by google as `activation.jar`,`additional.jar` and `mail.jar`.

Comment: Hi, if port `587` isn't working, try port `465`. Also, try reversing the emails (try sending from @gmail to `@softglobe.net`. Don't forget to [authorize](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) external access to your gmail account. If you weren't already, take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-send-an-email-with-javamail-api-in-android-2fc405441079)

Comment: @chornge I have followed the same tutorial and also tried with the port 465, but not working

Comment: Try sending from one `@gmail` account to another `@gmail` account. You can even use the same account (like the article). The reason is that the email protocol/settings for `@softglobe` might differ from `@gmail` settings

Comment: @chornge thanks, The email is sent from `@gmail` to `@softglobe` account, and also from `@gmail` to `@gmail` self account, but not sending from `@softglobe` to `@gmail` account. Why is this so?